# Debugging Forth using a Test Harness

Tags: debugging, testing, forth

I would like to use a simple test harness to test my code during debugging using the same methodology as the [Forth test harness](http://www.forth200x.org/documents/html/testsuite.html) developed by John Hayes.

The concept is to define a function, say `my+` and then to define simple code snippets that will test the code when `Tdebug` is on.

`Tdebug if T{ 1 1 my+ -> 2 }T else`

Is it really as simple as including [`tester.f`](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/30768829/) and changing `{>` to `T{` and `}` to `}T`?

I plan to omit `tester.f` in the production release if size is an issue.

Edit:

`debug if ... then` does not work because it is outside compile...

Now I need help!

If debug is true `tester.f` works well.

If debug is false `t{` and `}t` must work like `( ... )` comments.  How do I code this?

```
0 constant debug
: t{
debug if
  ( as defined in tester.fr )
else
  ( what goes here? )
then
;
: }t
debug if
  ( as defined in tester.fr )
else
  ( and what goes here? )
then
;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to parse the input source stream up to `}t`. If `t{` can be nested, it becomes a little trickier — see the [reference implementation](https://forth-standard.org/standard/tools/BracketELSE) of `[ELSE]` word.

For reference, the production-mode definition of `t{` word for simple (not nested) case in standard Forth:

```
: t{ ( "ccc }t" -- ) \ skip up to '}t'
  begin
    begin parse-name dup while S" }t" compare 0= until exit then 2drop
    refill 0= 
  until
;
```

Although, I suggest to place tests into separate files and make conditional inclusion of such files ("spec" files). In such case you don't need to have another (production-mode) definition of `t{` word at all.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did something similar to @ruvim by including tester.f when in debug mode and including notester.f when in production as follows:

```
\ notester.fs
( include either tester.fs or notester.fs )
\ adapted from longcomment.txt
false variable verbose
: t{ ( -- ) \ Long comment
  begin
    token  \ Get next token
    dup 0= if 2drop cr query token then \ If length of token is zero, end of 
                                        \ line is reached. 
                                        \ Fetch new line. Fetch new token.
    s" }t" compare  \ Search for }t
  until
  immediate 0-foldable
;
: testing  ( -- )                                            \ Talking comment.
source verbose @
if dup >r type cr r> >in !
else >in ! drop [char] * emit
then 
;
t{ 1 1 + -> 2 }t                                             \ Usage sample
```

I find that having the tests as usage comments in the production file assists clarity.

Comment: It seems that you have missed `0=` after `compare` (since it should return 0 on equal strings). Also it seems that you will get either exception or infinite loop in case of `}t` is not found up to the end of file.

Comment: @ruvim Code works fine without `0=` in Mecrisp.  I cannot remember missing `}t` causing unintended issues, but will check.

Comment: Oh, I see. In [Mecrisp](http://mecrisp.sourceforge.net/glossary.htm) `until` "loops as long flag is true". It controverts to [`until`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/UNTIL) in standard Forth. It is very bad practice in Mecrisp.

Comment: @ruvim ...loops as long as true... is only a documentation error.  I suspect that `compare` returns true for equal strings.

Comment: skvery, in such case it controverts to [`compare`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/string/COMPARE) in standard Forth. — It is not far better ;)